# Error: clsUser is not defined

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, app-code

I am importing an existing bunch of code files into a new solution. The solution contains only 1 project. I have a folder called `App_Code` which contains all cls object files.  On my aspx.vb code behind, I am getting an error on

```
`Dim cUser as clsUser`
```

and the error reads `clsUser is not defined`

The clsUser.vb file is in the App_Code folder (in the same project). The clsUser file is a Public class.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class clsUser
    Dim mUserID As Integer
    Dim mUpdateSeq As Integer
    Dim mUserName As String
```

[image]

How can I fix the error?

**Update:**  In the same project, I have an aspx file with a ddlStates DropDownList control and in the codebehind page, I have error that says `'ddlStates' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

Comment: Did you add clsUser.vb to your project?  Is the class declared in a different namespace - if yes, did you add that namespace to your `Imports` directives?

Comment: clsUser is added to the project. It's the same namespace

Comment: Best you show us the code in question, then.

Comment: By that I mean we should see more of the code in context - show the class definition of clsUser; at least enough to see the full file header.  Also show the context in which you are declaring `cUser` - more code is better.  What you have shown is not sufficient to offer help.  Your mistake is somewhere in the code you have not shown us.

Comment: `App_Code folder`??? It doesnt matter what folder it is in, projects can have many folders.  But the file has to be included in the project!

Comment: @Plutonix - he said in a comment that it is added to the project.

Comment: ...but to be sure, @user3929962 -- did you add it to the project ***in visual studio***?  ie : Right-click your project --> Add --> Add Existing Item... ?

Comment: @Plutonix yes it's all in the same project.

Comment: @J... yes, I did the right click--> Add --> Add Existing Item etc.... I have does this before in other projects and never had this issue. I updated my post to display the clsUser info.